# what makes my code snippet not working at all in vscode?

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

[image]

above is what I saw in tutorial video...it says many snippets so developer can use it

but as to my vscode...I can't select any function ! even on extension I installed many unity code snippets...
[image]

[image]

Comment: that are not snippets but Intellisense

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred to me and I tried to install a lot of C# and Unity plugins, but it didn't work until I completely deleted the vcode and re-downloaded it, and I downloaded one [c#](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp) extensions and one [Unity](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Unity.unity-debug) extensions

But the most important extension is [c#](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp).